# Native sysroot directory not found when executing runqemu nographic

Tags: python

I'm running `runqemu` `nographic` and getting this error:

```
/scratch/2-update-tag_dev_branches-script/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/qemu-helper-native/1.0-r1/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin doesn't exist.
```

I'm trying to `run qemu` for an ARM processor, but the path `runqemu` finds is still set to x86_64-linux and should be aarch64 which is a folder my path now contains.
I see for the runqemu code that the directory is somehow stored in the `STAGING_BINDIR_NATIVE` buffer:

```
def bindir_native(self):
        result = self.get('STAGING_BINDIR_NATIVE')
        if result and os.path.exists(result):
            return result

        cmd = ['bitbake', '-e']
        multiconfig = self.get('MULTICONFIG')
        if multiconfig:
            cmd.append('mc:%s:qemu-helper-native' % multiconfig)
        else:
            cmd.append('qemu-helper-native')

        logger.info('Running %s...' % str(cmd))
        out = subprocess.check_output(cmd).decode('utf-8')

        match = re.search('^STAGING_BINDIR_NATIVE="(.*)"', out, re.M)
        if match:
            result = match.group(1)
            if os.path.exists(result):
                self.set('STAGING_BINDIR_NATIVE', result)
                return result
            raise RunQemuError("Native sysroot directory %s doesn't exist" % result)
        else:
            raise RunQemuError("Can't find STAGING_BINDIR_NATIVE in '%s' output" % str(cmd))
```

I need to find out where `STAGING_BINDIR_NATIVE` is loaded with the actual path so I can change it to find my aarch64 directory.
Thanks.